# Объединененные данные из двух таблиц с помощью двух других

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно, совместить данные из двух таблиц вот как выглядит схема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице "лабиринт" есть данные, которых нет в "озоне", нужно совместить данные. Для этого я создал две таблицы , в которых записываю `book_id` и `isbn`.

Сделал я это так , потому-что у одной книги может быть много `isbn`

вот пример таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь мне нужно сравнить две таблицы `лабиринт_book_id` и `озон_book_id`, и сравнить их по `isbn`.

И уже исходя из этого, получить обобщенную информацию по книгам. Не знаю как написать этот запрос. Помогите. Хочу вывести данные в таблицу на веб-морде в таком виде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Немного конкретизирую вопрос**

Есть таблица "Лабиринт" с книгами я из нее беру `book_id` и `isbn`, то же самое делаю в озоне. Потом я эти две таблицы `лабиринт_book_id` и `озон_book_id` сравниваю по `isbn`, и, если, `isbn` совпали то беру `book_id` у совпавших записей в первой и второй таблице и беру по `book_id` из `озон_book_id` данные из озона, для лабиринта делаю тоже самые, просто у озона и лабиринта разные `book_id`. а название не важно из какой брать.

Comment: что на вашей верхней схеме означает разделение таблиц на 2 части, т.е. вынесение isbn и book_id в отдельную таблицу со стрелочкой ? И какое отношение к задачи имеет book_id если группировка судя по всему нужна по isbn. А еще откуда брать book_name если они вдруг разные в озоне и лабиринте

Comment: Есть таблица Лабиринт с книгами я из нее беру book_id и isbn, то же самое делаю в озоне. Потом я эти две таблицы лабиринт_book_id и озон_book_id сравниваю по isbn и если isbn совпали то беру book_id у совпавших записей в первой и второй таблице и беру по book_id из озон_book_id данные из озона, для лабиринта делаю тоже самые, просто у озона и лабиринта разные book_id. а название не важно из какой брать.

Comment: но раз у вас несколько isbn на один book_id то какой из cover_type брать если для данного book_id в лабиринте несколько разных isbn с разными cover_type

Comment: Нет, тут такая связь я сперва сравниваю лабиринт_book_id и озон_book_id нахожу совпадения по isbn если совпадение найдены, то у меня есть грубо говоря  получается так из лабиринт_book_id book_id: 322 isbn:1234 и озон_book_id book_id:430 isbn:1234. Затем я лезу по этим данным в лабиринт и беру книгу по book_id из лабиринт_book_id и тоже самое делаю для озона и создаю из них обощенные данные. Возможно это сделать?

Comment: возможно все. надо только задачу понять. А я пока не понимаю. Если вам достаточно просто сопоставить 322 и 430 то так и пишите в вопросе. А вы пишите про какие то page_type и cover_type которых много для одного book_id судя по приведенному вами примеру данных

Comment: И из вашего текущего вопроса вытекает что достаточно просто выполнить элементарный join по полю isbn. Хотя я подозреваю что проблема заключается в том что каких то isbn может не быть либо в одной либо в другой таблице. Но это чисто мои подозрения, этого в вопросе не сказано - значит и отвечать на это нет смысла

Comment: Да в таблице лабиринт isbn  к примеру приведены списком, через запятую, поэтому пришлось создать таблицу прослойку, чтобы их отделить, тоже самое в озоне. И да в одной таблице есть не все ,что есть в другой.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53081/discussion-between-shatoidil-and-mike).